# Implementing DQN - Pylessons.com article - Queries

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I have followed the below link to implement DQN Algorithm

https://pylessons.com/CartPole-reinforcement-learning/

Can someone explain me:

1. Why do we need to have else condition in act function during training? (Actually in my training, episode is ending successfully if I have only random action but not both random and predicted actions)
2. Why are we not just doing self.model.predict(state) in test function and instead looping several times again as in training?